# Trying to bleed clutch system

Tags: toyota, clutch-cylinder

Ok so I was finally able to bleed my clutch system. I even put a vacuum pump on it to try and get the air out. But no air. After trying that I had someone pumping on the clutch and then releasing the valve. But when the clutch is pressed in the slave cylinder goes back in. Does this mean the the slave cylinder is bad?[image]

Comment: Only way a slave is bad is if it leaks fluid.. You might post the Make Model, engine and year of you vehicle. Maybe a picture of the slave unit.

Comment: It's a 95 Toyota Tacoma 4x4. I've posted about it yesterday.

Comment: How do I add a picture. And I posted a comment on the other post. But didn't get a response. Didn't think it went anywhere unless someone happened to look at it. But now I know you get notified.

Comment: Ok pic added. The fluid is from me bleeding it. Before that it was dry.

Comment: About a year ago the slave cylinder and master cylinder were replaced. The clutch plate is staying engaged while pedal is pressed in.

Comment: Are you sure your self-adjusting clutch didn't adjust too far because your clutch is worn out? I went through this same pain on my old '87 Grand Am and at the end of the day the master and slave were fine... a new clutch fixed the problem.

Comment: Well it's only a year or less old. Everything was replaced.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I do when having a stubborn clutch slave bleeding problem.

I attach some tubing to an Oil can full of brake fluid, pump the oil can to purge air, then attach the end of the hose to the bleeder valve on the **slave cylinder**, open the bleeder and pump the oil can to force any air trapped up and into the master reservoir.

Be sure the oil can is thoroughly clean as you do not want any contamination of the brake fluid, also use new tubing or vacuum line of the appropriate size that will fit the bleeder tight.

Sometimes you can self bleed it by full stroking the clutch pedal a few hundred times but is hard on the leg, but sometimes this is the only thing that works, occasionally let the clutch pedal snap up (side step it at the bottom) from the depressed position during this routine.

[image]

If this does not solve it I suspect you have a Clutch Master cylinder that is bypassing, this will reduce the volume of fluid it can push, causing the slave to not extend as far as it needs to.

Comment: So then I would need a new clutch master cylinder then?

Comment: Yes, if you have tried everything I suggested.

Comment: That method is referred to as 'reverse bleeding.' There are companies that sell reverse bleeding tools.  I build one out of a sauce jar that hooks up to an air compressor, with a regulator to limit it to only a few PSI.

Comment: I know, I invented it....oil can is much easier.